# How to match part of the string contains certain word

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to be able to match the following texts

```
top of radio 54 / bottom 27
radio top 54 / bottom 27
```

The word `top` can be before or after `radio` only for the first half of the text (before `/`). `top` that appears after `/` should not be matched.

I tried to use the following pattern that encloses the lookahead for the first half with parentheses.

```
((?=top).*radio\s\d{2}\s)\/\D*bottom\s\d{2}
```

But it doesn't work like I expected. Only matches first string, but not second.

Comment: What are your expected matched from both lines?

Comment: @anubhava both lines should be matched

Comment: Try `((?:top\s+of\s+radio|radio\s+top)\s\d{2}\s)\/\D*bottom\s\d{2}`, see https://regex101.com/r/9FSqeI/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am aware this would work by explicitly declaring two different cases. I just thought it could have been done with lookahead in a simpler way since position doesn't matter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with a lookahead:

```bash
^(?=[^/]*\btop\s)[^/]*radio[^/]+\d{2}\s+/\D*bottom\s+\d{2}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LAieQu/3)

**RegEx Breakup:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=[^/]*\btop\s)`: Lookahead to assert presence of word `top` being present before matching a `/`. **This is to ensure we match word `top` before `/` only**
- `[^/]*`: Match 0 more of any char that is not a `/`
- `radio`: Match `radio`
- `[^/]+`: Match 1+ of any char that is not a `/`
- `\d{2}`: Match 2 digits
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespaces
- `/`: Match a `/`
- `\D*`: Match 0 or more non-digits
- `bottom`: Match `bottom`
- `\s+`: Match 1+ whitespace
- `\d{2}`: Match 2 digits
- `$`: End

Comment: what do the `[^/]`s do in this case

Comment: `[^/]` is negated character class that matches any char that is not `/`